# while controller action running, show user message

Tags: grails

while readcsv action is running, it will take several minutes to process data, depends on the file size, so when it is executing i want to know how to show message to user to tell them that data is in progress.. thx

```
 def readcsv() {
    redirect(action: "list")
    flash.message = "okokokok"
    def list = []
    def dir = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Summarize_20141212/ONE_FILE")
    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
        list << file
    }
    list.each {
    File file = new File(it.path)
    def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new",
            'postgres', 'sa', "org.postgresql.Driver")
    def linecount = 0
    file.eachLine() { line ->
        if (line.trim().size() == 0) {
            return null
        } else {
            def field = []
            def tokens = line.split(',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')
            file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }
            linecount++
            field.push(file.name)

            for (String t : tokens) {

                field.push(t)
            }
            while (field.size() < 10) {
                field.push("")
            }
            if (linecount > 1) {
                sql.execute('insert into read_csv(version,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10) ' +
                        'VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', field)
                System.out.println(field);
            }
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the coding that actually show the render message while the process is running, if i want show the def list() page after the processing, how to do it? if i just add redict at the end the render message will not display anymore..
....

```
def readcsv() {
        def asyncProcess = new Thread({
            def list = []
            def dir = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Summarize_20141212/ONE_FILE")
            dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
                list << file
            }
            list.each {
                File file = new File(it.path)
                def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new",
                        'postgres', 'sa', "org.postgresql.Driver")
                def linecount = 0
                file.eachLine() { line ->
                    if (line.trim().size() == 0) {
                        return null
                    } else {
                        def field = []
                        def tokens = line.split(',(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)')
                        file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }
                        linecount++
                        field.push(file.name)

                        for (String t : tokens) {

                            field.push(t)
                        }
                        while (field.size() < 10) {
                            field.push("")
                        }
                        if (linecount > 1) {
                            sql.execute('insert into read_csv(version,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10) ' +
                                    'VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', field)
                            System.out.println(field);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        } as Runnable )
        asyncProcess.start()
        render "Your file is being processed"


    }
```

Comment: async is not bound to the actions of your app, once triggered it will do what it needs to do in the background(unaware of what it is that triggered it etc etc). Like render there is another command called forward which you could use outside of your asyncProcess.start I will update my answer

Comment: added it ? can you not see forward and render commented out ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really move the functionality of your csv reader into a service and get your controller to call it. On possiblity could be the use of async:

```
class MyController {
def myService
def readcsv() {

def asyncProcess = new Thread({
    myService.readCSV(filename, input2,input3) 
  } as Runnable )

asyncProcess.start() 
forward (action: 'list')    
//render "Your file is being processed"


 //forward (controller:"someController", action: 'someAction', model [param1: params.param1 param2: param2:params.param2 ])

}
```

Have a read of async here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html

Besides your forward, you could use the following variations

Render: Where render then loads in actual page you wish to show rather than current action... so in this case list

```
render (view: 'list', model: [params:params])
```

Or maybe even

Chain : http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/chain.html

```
chain(action: "details", model: [book: shawshankRedemption])
```

And finally redirect

```
redirect (controller: 'admin', action: 'welcome')
redirect(url: request.getHeader('referer'))
redirect(action: "show", id: some.id)
redirect(action: "list", params: params)
```

Comment: hi i tried it but the rendered message only showed at the end.....i expected it to show at beginning .....

Comment: Are you sure?, if it is going via async then the task is put in background in effect. It may be that your task is completing real quick and it appears that way. Try putting in a long sleep time in the service doing the csv parsing and see if the render message appears first.

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=async used it a variety of times here - works fine for me https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/jssh/JsshService.groovy#L124 notice this one specifically around sleep and send msg -